# Metric space and its ball

Tags: metric-spaces

how can it be shown that the ball $B(a,5)$ may be a proper subset of $B(b,3)$ in a metric space, but if $B(a,6)\subseteq B(b,3)$, then they are equal?

Comment: The only thing you'll use is the triangle inequality. For the second part, use that two sets are the same iff one is contained in the other and vice versa.

Comment: the admin edited question but in original version, B(a,6) is proper subset of B(b,3), no equality.

Comment: @JohnStern If (as in original version) $B(a,6)$ is a proper subset of $B(b,3)$ then still it can be proved that $B(b,3)\subseteq B(a,6)$. But then we find that $B(b,3)$ is a proper subset of itself. This contradiction shows that $B(a,6)$ cannot be a proper subset of $B(b,3)$ and based on the false statement that it is everything can be concluded.

Answer (score 2):

If $B(a,6)\subseteq B(b,3)$ and $x\in B(b,3)$ then $d(a,x)\leq d(a,b)+d(b,x)< 3+3=6$ so that $x\in B(a,6)$. This proves that $B(b,3)\subseteq B(a,6)$ and consequently $B(b,3)=B(a,6)$.

---

Now let set $(0,6)\subseteq\mathbb R$ be the underlying set of the metric space, and let it be equipped with usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$.

Then  $B(3,3)=(0,6)$ so it contains properly **every** proper subset of $(0,6)$.

The ball $B(0.5,5)$ is such a proper subset of $(0,6)$.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part suppose that $B(a,6)\subset B(b,3)$, we show that $B(b,3)\subset B(a,6)$. Let $x\in B(b,3)$, $d(a,x)\leq d(a,b)+d(b,x)\leq 3+3=6$.